# What are some good books on basics of Cell signaling?

Tags: molecular-biology, book-recommendation, cell-signaling

I think the title says it all.
(self answered, although others' answers requested)

Comment: Why these close votes? Do you have any suggestion to improve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ***Cellular Signal Processing*** (an introduction to the molecular mechanisms of signal transduction), by Frederich Marks, Ursula Klingmuler, Karin Muller-Decker;
   Garland/Taylor-Francis.

[image: Book cover showing book by Marks, Klingmuler and Muller-decker]

Link: [CRC book](https://www.crcpress.com/Cellular-Signal-Processing-An-Introduction-to-the-Molecular-Mechanisms/Marks-Klingmuller-Muller-Decker/p/book/9780815345343), [Google books](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Cellular_Signal_Processing.html?id=0TIWBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

.............

2. ***Structure and function  in Cell signaling*** by John Nelson, Wiley.

[image: John Nelson book]

Link:  [Wiley](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Structure+and+Function+in+Cell+Signalling-p-9780470025512), [Google books](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Structure_and_Function_in_Cell_Signallin.html?id=qmprSCPkfPcC&redir_esc=y)